# React dynamic form from API performance

Tags: reactjs, forms, performance

I'm building forms according to what is returned from an API.

I build the state that fields will need to access and then store the return of this function, it returns an array of fields, on the state

```
  const CreateMainFields = (
    fd = fields,
    currSection = "default",
    f = form,
    sf = setForm
  ) => {
    return fd.map(itm => {
      if (itm.type === "section") {
        return (
          <section key={`section_${itm.id}`}>
            <Typography id={`section_${itm.id}`} variant="h6">
              {itm.label}
            </Typography>
            {CreateMainFields(itm.fields, itm.id)}
          </section>
        );
      } else if (itm.type === "field") {
        console.log(f, f[itm.formValue]);
        return (
          <TextField
            label={itm.label}
            value={f[itm.formValue]}
            onChange={e => {
              const value = e.currentTarget.value;
              sf(old => ({ ...old, [itm.formValue]: value }));
            }}
            key={`field_${itm.formValue}`}
            variant="filled"
          />
        );
      }
      return null;
    });
  };



//Create the fields once the form state is ready
  useEffect(() => {
    if (form && formListReady.current) setContent(CreateMainFields(fields));
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [form]);
```

Dynamically building the form according to a variable, be it from redux or state, is easy, the problem I'm getting is how to do so in a way that doesn't affects performance. The forms can be extense and since I'm storing form data on the state everytime the user types I re-render the whole thing.

Here's a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dyanmic-form-35uqr?file=/src/Visits.js

Are there any improvements I can make besides keeping form size as short as possible?

Comment: One thing would be to not use an arrow function for the `onChange` handler of `<TextField>`.  This is a known performance issue.  React always considers these functions unequal in equality checks during render.